# Polymorphic object creation without IF condition

Tags: c#, oop

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Records
    {
        public string Type;
        public string Source;
        public int Value;

        protected Records(string type, string source, int value)
        {
            Type = type;
            Source = source;
            Value = value;
        }
}
```

I would like to create many classes inheriting this class, and filling their Type field with a value coming from a static class like this:

```
public static class ContentTypesString
    {
        public static string DocumentNew { get { return "Document - New this Month"; }}

        public static string HeadlinesNew { get { return "Headlines - New this Month"; }}

       etc...  
    }
```

I would like to be able to create those child classes without having a test "`if foo == "document" then type = ContentTypesString.DocumentNew`" or an equivalent switch case (I really have a lot of cases)

Is there a design pattern that suits my needs?

EDIT : As several people pointed out, i should show how i create my instances.

```
     private delegate SPListItemCollection Query(SPWeb web, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
     private readonly Query _queries;

       #region Constructors

      public QueryHandler(SPWeb web, DateTime startTimeSelectedDate, DateTime endTimeSelectedDate)
          {
            if (web == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("web");

            _web = web;
            _startTimeSelectedDate = startTimeSelectedDate;
            _endTimeSelectedDate = endTimeSelectedDate;
            RecordsList = new List<Records>();

            // Query Invocation List
            _queries = NumberPagePerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberDocumentsPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberHeadlinesPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberLeaderboxPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberNewsPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberPagesModifiedPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberPicturesPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
            _queries += NumberTeasingPerMonthQuery.PreparedQuery;
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        // what about NullReferenceException ? C#6 : item?.Foreach(item => {}); ?
        /*** NO C#6 compiler in VS2012... ***/
        public void Queries()
        {
            foreach (var del in _queries.GetInvocationList())
            {
                var queryresult =
                    (SPListItemCollection) del.DynamicInvoke(_web, _startTimeSelectedDate, _endTimeSelectedDate);

                RecordsList.Add(new Records(del.Method.Name, _web.Title, queryresult.Count));
            }
        }
```

**EDIT²** : 
The solution i chose

```
  public List<IQuery> QueryList { get; } // no delegate anymore, and static classes became implementations of IQuery interface.

       #region Constructors

      public QueryHandler(SPWeb web, DateTime startTimeSelectedDate, DateTime endTimeSelectedDate)
          {
            if (web == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("web");

            _web = web;
            _startTimeSelectedDate = startTimeSelectedDate;
            _endTimeSelectedDate = endTimeSelectedDate;
            RecordsList = new List<Records>();

            QueryList = new List<IQuery>
            {
                new NumberDocumentsPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberHeadlinesPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberLeaderboxPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberNewsPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberPagePerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberPagesModifiedPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberPicturesPerMonthQuery(),
                new NumberTeasingPerMonthQuery()
            };

        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        // what about NullReferenceException ? C#6 : item?.Foreach(item => {}); ?
        /*** NO C#6 compiler in VS2012... ***/
          public void Queries()
        {
            foreach (var query in QueryList)
            {
                var queryresult = query.PreparedQuery(_web, _startTimeSelectedDate, _endTimeSelectedDate);
                RecordsList.Add(query.CreateRecord(_web.Title, queryresult.Count));
            }
        }
```

Record class follow the implementation suggested by @dbraillon
Implementation of IQuery interface were added the method :

```
public Records CreateRecord(string source, int value)
        {
            return new ModifiedPagesPerMonthRecord(source, value); //or another child of Record class. 
        }
```

And voilà. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Why not just do it inside the inherited class? `public class Documents : Records { public Documents() { Type = ContentTypesString.DocumentNew; } }`

Comment: Why not just put some virtual method getDefaultContentTypeString?

Comment: yes, but how can i choose which Records child to make without IF in the caller ?

Comment: @Will : yes, there was an error on constructor name. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: @YthioCsi In what caller? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @YthioCsi, but how can we know what you need to do and how you do it right now?

Comment: Please add the current code for creating the object with IF conditions

Comment: I added the necessary code to show the records creation. There isn't any if yet because i didn't write them but if i do it would probably be a if with the Method.Name and the names in my delegate invocation list, calling the right Record child constructor.

Comment: I think i found, i changed my program a lot. The static utility methods that hold preparedQuery became implementations of an IQuery interface, the delegate have been replaced by a List<IQuery>, and the delegate invocation list replaced by a foreach on the list<IQuery> calling the interface method. Implementation of the interface also hold a method that return the desired Record child instance.

Comment: @YthioCsi, lol but you did't show how you create specific realisation of IQuery that build specific record

Comment: What was replaced by the IQuery was static methods in the delegate invocation list. I could have been clearer indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make collection of records, by string code of object type, and parameters.

One of many way to do it - use builder.

Firstly we need to configurate builder:

```
        var builder = new RecordBuilder()
            .RegisterBuilder("document", (source, value) => new Document(source, value))
            .RegisterBuilder("headlines", (source, value) => new Headlines(source, value));
```

here we specify how to build record with code "document" and "headlines".

To build a record call:

```
        builder.Build("document", "source", 1);
```

Builder code can by something like this
(here we look if we know how to build record of the passed type and make it):

```
public class RecordBuilder
{
    public Records Build(string code, string source, int value)
    {
        Func<string, int, Records> buildAction;

        if (recordBuilders.TryGetValue(code, out buildAction))
        {
            return buildAction(source, value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public RecordBuilder RegisterBuilder(string code, Func<string, int, Records> buildAction)
    {
        recordBuilders.Add(code, buildAction);
        return this;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, Func<string, int, Records>> recordBuilders = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, int, Records>> ();
}


public class Document : Records
{
    public Document(string source, int value) : base(ContentTypesString.DocumentNew, source, value)
    {
    }
}

public class Headlines : Records
{
    public Headlines(string source, int value) : base(ContentTypesString.HeadlinesNew, source, value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you are doing here and how to use it, but it certainly looks more like the (very) vague memory of a design that i'm trying to reproduce here.

Comment: I think i found, i changed my program a lot. The static utility methods that hold preparedQuery became implementations of an IQuery interface, the delegate have been replaced by a List<IQuery>, and the delegate invocation list replaced by a foreach on the list<IQuery> calling the interface method. Implementation of the interface IQuery also hold a method that return the desired Record child instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need ?

```
public abstract class Records
{
    public string Type;
    public string Source;
    public int Value;

    protected Records(string type, string source, int value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Source = source;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class DocumentRecords : Records
{
    public DocumentRecords(string source, int value)
        : base(ContentTypesString.DocumentNew, source, value) // use here
    {
    }
}

public class HeadlinesRecords : Records
{
    public HeadlinesRecords(string source, int value)
        : base(ContentTypesString.HeadlinesNew, source, value) // use here
    {
    }
}

public static class ContentTypesString
{
    public static string DocumentNew { get { return "Document - New this Month"; } }

    public static string HeadlinesNew { get { return "Headlines - New this Month"; } }
}
```

Comment: That looks good :) But how can i choose which Records child to make without IF in the caller ?

Comment: So at first, you only have a type and you want to give that type to something that will create corresponding Records child back to you ?

Comment: I added some code about how i create the Records instances. I would like to get rid of the Method.Name which is quite dirty in my opinion and call the right Record child class constructor in this context. I have vague memories it is possible but i don't remember how.

Comment: I think i found, i changed my program a lot. The static utility methods that hold preparedQuery became implementations of an IQuery interface, the delegate have been replaced by a List<IQuery>, and the delegate invocation list replaced by a foreach on the list<IQuery> calling the interface method. Implementation of the interface also hold a method that return the desired Record child instance.